# '86 Ford Ranger won't start

Tags: electrical, ford, battery, starting, truck

For a while my truck's ignition has been acting up and I would have to roll the ignition. back and fourth several times before it would start but one day I went to crank it and the truck acted like it had no battery at all in it. No warning lights/lamps would come on, horn wont work, and the usually open door buzz wasn’t there. any reasons to why it may have done this and are there any parts I should replace that might help?

Comment: Its a brand new battery and i put new terminals on it too.

Comment: Possible electrical ground strap terminal connection loose or corroded somewhere?

Comment: Bad ignition switch (lower steering column, replace it, sometimes it burns the wires at the switch and you have to repair the wire ends with new ones...http://www.rockauto.com/en/moreinfo.php?pk=1006195&cc=1137473&jsn=448

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the battery condition? Your local motor parts supplier should be able to test it for you, and replace it if it's failed.

As a guide, batteries usually last 5-8 years, so if it's in that range or older, you'll probably need to replace it.

Also check the condition of the connections to the battery terminals, and the condition of the grounding straps to the battery.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely a Bad ignition switch (lower steering column), replace it, sometimes it burns the big 12v wires at the switch and you have to repair the wire ends with new ones or get a ignition switch repair pigtail and splice it in.

[image]